# onSharedPreferenceChanged() never called after a clear()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with SharedPreferences and its listener.
I use only one SharedPreference instance in my app that I retrieve with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

In my PreferenceFragment, I have a button to reset the preference to default. That's what it does:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).edit().clear().commit();
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.settings, true);
```

I have several listeners for this SharedPreference. They all work perfectly on addition/modification of my keys. But **they never get fired** on a reset. The doc isn't specific about this case, but states:

> *onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)*
>
> Called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed.

And for me a reset is a removal of all preferences, so I'm expecting it the callback to happen.

Why doesn't it happen?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you trying to clear the preference values, is that what you want when the reset button is clicked

Comment: I clear (= remove all) the preference values, then load the defaults from my file R.xml.settings. But neither of both fires a `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` callback.

Comment: I think if You clear the SP, also the Listeners are removed. There is no documentation about , but maybe , after clear(), register this listeners again.

Comment: @Dadou: i dont actually understand your context but i can suggest one solution, you can rewrite the values with the old ones in the button click..now the preference values are changed..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I checked: the listeners are receiving modifications before and after the clear, but not the clear itself.

Comment: @George That could work partially but I would keep the old keys that don't have a default value to replace theirs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a feature and not really documented well. Here's an explanation based on reading the source.

Think of shared preferences as a key-value `Map` that can be persisted in mass memory. Then think of `SharedPreferences.Editor` as another `Map` that just stores the modifications to be applied on `apply()` or `commit()`. Removals are stored as `null` values. `clear()` is implemented just as a boolean flag in the editor and when set, the target shared preferences map is cleared before applying the changes.

Listeners are notified on a per-key basis. There's no information about the keys that were in the shared preferences map prior to clearing it. So you only get notifications about those changes that were specified by a key name in the editor.

It could have been implemented otherwise, too: It would be only a few lines of code to record the `keySet()` of the existing shared preferences in modified keys before clearing the map.

For reference: [`SharedPreferencesImpl` source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java)

Comment: Perfect answer, great link, looking at the source code indeed confirms what you're saying. Thanks!

Comment: In Android R, OnSharedPreferenceChanged is triggered even when you call clear() on the Editor. link https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener